# Figures all over the show in latex in overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am having issues with a report I am writing. First time using latex and after getting some help on here regarding some tables weirdness I again have a silly frustrating issue. Figures don't stay where I put them. I made a MWE Posted Below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }

%%%%%% Referencing %%%%%%
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
The average sea surface temperature (SST) trend is shown in Figure \ref{fig:SST}.
\section{Figures}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{Figures/SST.png}
  \label{fig:SST}
\end{figure}
\section{References}
\bibliography{References.bib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\end{document}
```

I expect, probably an error, for the figure to be inserted under the Figures subheading however it appears on the next page after references. I have to refer to my figure in the text, hence the \ref{fig:SST} so it is clickable. It's not a size issue as there is more than enough space on the page to accommodate the figure. Even if that was the issue I would expect the references subheading to be after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most latex classes use so called `floats` for figures, tables etc. The idea is that latex will automatically find a good place for your images and avoid ugly white space.

To make use of the abilities of latex to produce a good looking output, you must specify possible placements with floating specifier such as `[htbp]`, which allows latex to place the image here, at the top, at the bottom or an a separate page.

Also if you want to use the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism, your figure must have a caption (and the label inside or after the caption).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }

%%%%%% Referencing %%%%%%
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
The average sea surface temperature (SST) trend is shown in Figure \ref{fig:SST}.
\section{Figures}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{test}
  \label{fig:SST}
\end{figure}
\section{References}
\bibliography{References.bib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My report requires all the figures to be placed all together at the end of the document. I don't know why because it looks hideous but here we are... This solution worked perfectly thankyou. Adding figures with links, captions, and citations all at once wasn't proving easy! :)

Comment: If having all of the figures appear at the end of the document is a requirement (I think this is a bit of a hangover from when publishers expected to have to handle figures themselves), then you might use the `endfloat` package.  You include `{float}` environments within the document as usual, but they _all_ float to the very end.  Then you remove the package, and all of the figures float back to more natural places.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, LaTeX's attitude is ‘you write the text, let me worry about placing the figures’.

Floats (that is, figures and tables) *will* float to where LaTeX thinks they go best.  I can't remember the precise rules in the article style, but generally they float to the top of the nearest following page that has room for them.  LaTeX won't fill too much of a page with figures, so  if you have a dense sequence of large-ish figures, some of them can end up quite a long way away from the point in the source text where they're written.

This is normal, and how figures and tables appear in the majority of published books and articles.

You'll usually write a caption:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{...blah...}
\caption{This is a caption for my figure\label{fig:SST}}
\end{figure}
```

Then you can write

```
...this is shown in Figure~\ref{fig:SST}
```

If you want to, you might add `...on p.\thinspace\pageref{fig:SST}` and LaTeX will insert the page number where the figure ends up.  Also, see the `prettyref` package.

As mentioned in the other answer, you can add placement specifiers like `[ht]`, which give LaTeX permission to put the figure ‘here’ *or* at the top of a page, but that doesn't force anything.  It is possible to fight with LaTeX about this (the [Overleaf docs](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_images_and_tables) give some hints), but it's generally not worth it in my experience.

That said, one bit of guidance it's useful to give LaTeX is something like `\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.8}`, which says that LaTeX is allowed to use as much as 80% of the page for floats (ie, figures and tables) – the default value is a bit tight (there are more comments on this in [this TeX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/) – `tex.stackexchange.com` is generally a better site for LaTeX-related questions).

If you do feel compelled to fight/fiddle with float placement, do it at the very end of the process, where you're fine-tuning the punctuation of your document.  Small changes in the document can have big effects on where floats end up, and it's simply not worth worrying about this until your document is almost finalised.

Your final puzzlement was about the figure ending up after the references.  In the case of your document, the figure goes on p.2, so there's plenty of space on p.1 for LaTeX to carry on setting text, so naturally it puts the references there.  Since you generally *do* want the references to go at the very end of an article, this is a case where it's reasonable to exert a little control over placement, and a good idea would be to put `\clearpage` before the References section.  What that does is to make a new page *and* force out any floats which are still in the queue waiting for space to appear.